# Python logging with python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

In my script, I have defined below code for `logging.` my main script will call additional sub python scripts. so to differentiate between those scripts, I have added custom `%(FILENAME)s` in my log file setup.

```
from telegrambot import *
import logging
import asyncio

# Get the name of each script without extension to include in log file
class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.FILENAME = record.filename[:-3].upper()
        return True


# Define logging function
def setup_logging():
    log_basename = "/home/acr/logs/daily-data"  # location of log file
    log_format = f'%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(FILENAME)s - %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(filename=f"{log_basename}_{dt.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H_%M_%S')}.log", level=logging.INFO,
                        format=log_format)
    f = ContextFilter()
    logging.getLogger().addFilter(f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup_logging()
    asyncio.run(send_telegram_message("Script is starting"))
```

and telegrambot.py:

```
 import telegram
 import asyncio
 import logging
    
    TOKEN = <token>
    chat_id = <id>
    
    async def send_telegram_message(msg):
        bot = telegram.Bot(TOKEN)
        try:
            async with bot:
                response = await bot.send_message(text=msg, chat_id=chat_id)
                if response and response.message_id:
                    logging.info(f"Message sent successfully with ID: {response.message_id}")
                else:
                    logging.error("Message sending failed.")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error sending message: {e}")
```

While running this script, Log file is getting created, but it always throwing below message:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 449, in format
    return self._format(record)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 445, in _format
    return self._fmt % values
           ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
KeyError: 'FILENAME'
3e8
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1110, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 953, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 690, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 659, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 451, in format
    raise ValueError('Formatting field not found in record: %s' % e)
ValueError: Formatting field not found in record: 'FILENAME'
Call stack:
  File "\\wsl$\Ubuntu-22.04\home\acr\algotrading\daily-data\dd.py", line 46, in <module>
    asyncio.run(send_telegram_message(telmsgstart))
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 640, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 321, in run_forever
    super().run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 607, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1919, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "\\wsl$\Ubuntu-22.04\home/acr/algotrading/common-modules\telegrambot.py", line 17, in send_telegram_message
    async with bot:
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\_bot.py", line 314, in __aenter__
    await self.initialize()
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\_bot.py", line 729, in initialize
    await self.get_me()
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\_bot.py", line 519, in decorator
    result = await func(self, *args, **kwargs)  # skipcq: PYL-E1102
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\_bot.py", line 769, in get_me
    result = await self._post(
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\_bot.py", line 607, in _post
    return await self._do_post(
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\_bot.py", line 635, in _do_post
    return await request.post(
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\request\_baserequest.py", line 168, in post
    result = await self._request_wrapper(
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\request\_baserequest.py", line 278, in _request_wrapper
    code, payload = await self.do_request(
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\request\_httpxrequest.py", line 219, in do_request
    res = await self._client.request(
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1530, in request
    return await self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1617, in send
    response = await self._send_handling_auth(
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1645, in _send_handling_auth
    response = await self._send_handling_redirects(
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1682, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = await self._send_single_request(request)
  File "C:\Users\ssss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1729, in _send_single_request
    logger.info(
Message: 'HTTP Request: %s %s "%s %d %s"'
Arguments: ('POST', URL('https://api.telegram.org/botxxxxxx128:AAxxx1xxxxxxxxxxxx/getMe'), 'HTTP/1.1', 200, 'OK')
```

This error looks like complaining about the `%(FILENAME)s` in the logger. How can I resolve this ?

Comment: The docs of [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/logging.html?highlight=basicconfig#logging.basicConfig) specify the keyword `filename` - try using the lowercase version instead of `FILENAME`